# AngularJS - on ng-click display another div

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. What I have done till now is, I have one controller and it's displaying some data. What I would like to do it, on-click on that data, display different div. What is the best way to do this ? Would like to follow MVC pattern. Also want to pass some data to another div.

Thanks

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="Aircraft">
    <div>
        Search: <input ng-model="search.AC">
        <table style="width:500px">
            <tbody style="background-color:#4db4fa; ">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">AC</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fleet</th>
                    <th scope="col">FltNum</th>
                    <th scope="col">StnFrom</th>
                    <th scope="col">StnTo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="Aircrafts in FlightAndAircraft | filter:search" align="center">
                    <td><button ng-click=" **** ***** HIDE THIS DIV AND DISPLAY NEXT DIV AND PASS {{Aircrafts.AC}} ***** *****" >{{Aircrafts.AC}} </button></td>
                    <td> {{Aircrafts.Fleet}}    </td>
                    <td> {{Aircrafts.FltNum}}   </td>
                    <td> {{Aircrafts.StnFrom}}  </td>
                    <td> {{Aircrafts.StnTo}}    </td>
                    <td> {{Aircrafts.Status}}   </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table style="width:500px">
            <tbody style="background-color:#4db4fa; ">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">AC</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fleet</th>

                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="Aircrafts in FlightAndAircraft | filter:search" align="center" ng-click="go(Aircrafts)">
                    <td> {{Aircrafts.AC}}       </td>
                    <td> {{Aircrafts.Fleet}}    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first `div` is clicked, you can set a variable indicating whether or not the next `div` should be visible.  Then, use `ng-if` to render, or `ng-hide`/`ng-show` to make the next `div` visible.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in people" class="badge" >
    <div ng-click="p.visible = !p.visible">{{p.id}}</div>
    <div ng-if="p.visible" class="badge alert-success">{{p.name}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a sample model.

```
$scope.people = [{name: 'igor', id: 0}, {name: 'misko', id: 1}];
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/yJ0CuSsm25N4VAI1hBDZ

**Update**

You can do something like this to show the next row of your aircraft table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Aircrafts in FlightAndAircraft" align="center" ng-show="visible.index == $index">
    <td> 
      <input type="button" ng-click="visible.index = $index + 1" value={{Aircrafts.AC}} /> 
    </td>
    <td> {{Aircrafts.Fleet}}    </td>
    <td> {{Aircrafts.FltNum}}   </td>
    <td> {{Aircrafts.StnFrom}}  </td>
    <td> {{Aircrafts.StnTo}}    </td>
    <td> {{Aircrafts.Status}}   </td>
</tr>
```

New demo: http://plnkr.co/raF3CTlaErgoVHQhRJA1

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable to know that the user has clicked on data. Supposing that your data are numbers:

controller:

```
$scope.numbers = [1,2,3,25,78,96];
$scope.clicked = false;
```

html:

```
<button ng-click="clicked=true">Click</button>

<div ng-show="clicked">
  <span ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{ number }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not set numbers because there are 1000 numbers and can get changed.

Comment: It was just a hard coded example. I just mean that to show another div, you can use ng-show with a condition, for example a variable inside your scope.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
<div ng-controller="showAppCtrl">
  <button ng-click="showDiv = ! showDiv">Toggle</button>
  <h1>{{val}}</h1>
  <div id="upper" ng-show="showDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum fuga voluptatem vero eos itaque nihil dolores quis eveniet repudiandae esse earum assumenda cumque laborum est porro quaerat quia accusamus amet.</div>
</div>

var App = angular.module("App", [])
          .controller('showAppCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.val = "Something to be shown";


          });
```

[**BIN DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/wikus/1/)